# How to license Windows VMs automatically on ESXi Host?

Tags: vmware, vmware-tools

I wanted to know whether it is possible to install and activate a Windows VM (Win10, WinServer) automatically, if you deploy the VM via REST API on VMWare?

I do not want to flood the whole json request here and flood the post with code. So I do not show the json request here.

For example, let's say we take the standard recommended json request with default parameters of VMware documentation, just to create a simple Windows 10 VM on VMWare.

The REST API documentation tells me that I have to do a POST request to:

```
POST https://{server}/rest/vcenter/vm
```

My question is now: is it possible to add a key for example 'license key' to deploy the VM with an valid license automatically?

If not, do someone know how to automate this task in a different way?
I am open to any advice, even for any other options.

Another option, which I thought up for myself, was to automatically license the VM through a shell access. However, SSH must be activated for this, which again causes a manual work step. I WANT TO AUTOMATE IT!

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is available via REST. You would have to instead reference the vSphere Web Services API to perform this action.